# Find the area bounded by the curve $y=\ln x$, $y=\frac xe$ and the x y axis

Tags: definite-integrals

$\ln x$ intersects the y axis at $-\infty$

So
$$A=\int_{-\infty}^{e} \ln x \,dx-\int_{-\infty}^{e} \frac xe dx$$

Which isn’t really a proper definite integral since I am having trouble applying the limits

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand $\int_{-\infty}^e\ln x\,dx$: the domain of $\ln$ is $(0\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lower bounds should be $0$ since the $y$-axis is stated as a bound. Then the integral is
$$\int_0^e(x/e-\ln x)\,dx=[x^2/2e-x\ln x+x]_0^e=\frac e2$$

Comment: I'd worry about knowing that, (as you have an improper integral) as the lower limit tends towards zero, $xlnx$ tends to zero. You have assumed it does. Luckily it does but to prove it, the easiest way would be via L'Hospital's Rule. I mention this because the question indicates that limits should be being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that due to $\ln x$ being one of the function, an immediate constraint is $ x>0$ , so we only have to consider half of the $x-y$ plane.

#### Sketching the graph:

[image]

Legend:
Red = ln(x), blue = $ \frac{x}{e}$

Observe both curves intersect at x=e.

Hence, we can by inspection write down area under curve as:

$$ |\int_0^1 \ln x dx| + \int_0^1 x dx + \int_1^e ( x - \ln x ) dx$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Considering the graphs of $y = \frac x e$ and $y = \ln x$, the bounds should be $(0,e)$, and $\frac x e > \ln x$. Hence you are looking for the integral:

$$\int_0^e \left(\frac xe - \ln x\right) \ dx$$